# Is there a way to fix/delete pars of a df.groupby output?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to see if I can remove and move elements from a df.groupby call.

```
week_df = df.groupby(["day_of_the_week"])['delivery_time'].mean().sort_values(ascending = False).astype(int)
print("The mean delivery time on weekdays and weekends is:", round(week_df), "minutes")
```

This codeblock gives the following output:

```
The mean delivery time on weekdays and weekends is: day_of_the_week Weekday 28 
Weekend 22 
Name: delivery_time, dtype: int64 minutes
```

Is there a way to delete both "day_of_the_week" in the first line and move "minutes" from the last line to be after both numbers (28 and 22) and delete the final line completely ("Name:, etc.)?

Comment: You may get more success with your question if you include a [mre] that can be run - this includes some demo dataframe for starters, probably some includes as well. See [ask].

Comment: Got it Patrick thanks. This is a bloody great site!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> print("The mean delivery time on weekdays and weekends is:\n", (week_df.round().astype(int).astype(str)+" minutes").to_string())
```

Comment: Thanks. Still can't get rid of the last line "Name: delivery_time, dtype: object"?

Comment: @RobertShaw - I edited my answer. Please re-try.

Comment: Thanks man. I really appreciate the help. The .to_string() seems not to work as it clashes with .round and .astype(int).

Comment: Not sure why. The answer works fine for me on pandas 1.4.1